# Not set hdpi or x-hdpi images in Micro-max funbook tablet Android

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I had develop app which compatibility for all device as well as tablets, I had put all images in `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi` and `xhdpi` it work for all device but it is not get images `hdpi` or `xhdpi` for tablets.

I had also set all support screen permission in android manifest file.

How I can overcome this problem does anybody have idea please help me.

Answer (score 3):

you need to put your images in

```
drawable-large-hdpi for 7" tablet
drawable-large-xhdpi for 10" tablet
```

it will solve my problem
i have used `drawable-large-hdpi` for my samsung galaxy 7" tablet.
and it works fine.

Comment: i had set all images like you said but micromax funbook takes ldpi only images.

Comment: can you tell what are the supports-screens require for tablets and sdk version?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html from here you will find all your answer.